# Autodesk forge - markup extension - create new EditMode tool

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

This is very similar to the question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60871333/how-to-create-new-markup-tool-in-markups-core-extension) but nothing useful was mentioned.

I'm trying to look for documentation on how to create a new EditMode tool for the markup extension. Documentation is very scarce and I can't find the source code for markup extensions. The only thing I can find is [here](https://autodesk-forge.gitee.io/viewer-docs/tutorial-feature_markup.html).

I'm trying to decipher this file: https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/extensions/Markup/Markup.js but it has a lot of webpack references and is hard to read.

Has anyone managed to create a custom EditMode tool?

### Edit

A member of my team has managed to find the source for the markup extension:

https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers/latest/docs/extensions_Markup_core_Markup.js.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, implementing a custom markup type is *not* officially supported today. The documentation you found (https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers/latest/docs/tutorial-feature_markup.html#create-a-new-drawing-tool-a-new-editmode) is *not* production ready.

Edit:

While I still believe the markup code is *not* ready for custom markup implementation, here's a work-in-progress, custom markup tool drawing smiley faces:
https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-basic-app/blob/sample/custom-markup/public/smiley-markup.js

In the sample app it is activated with a button click:
https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-basic-app/blob/sample/custom-markup/public/main.js#L11-L20

And here it is in action: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pAHo.jpg

Comment: I'm currently exploring the feasibility of creating new markup types (and planning on sharing my findings on https://forge.autodesk.com/blog). But so far the process of extending `Markup`, `EditMode`, and various `EditAction` classes is... not straightforward at all, so I'm going to talk to the Forge Viewer engineering team to see if they could provide higher-level, easy-to-extend classes instead.

Comment: Thank you for this, the links to your examples are extremely helpful. Can you come back and update your answer with a link to the blog once written please?

Comment: another question for you, how did you get this far, do you have the source code for the EditMode's that ship with Markup extensions?

Comment: Yep, I based my code on the implementation of `MarkupCircle`, `CircleEditMode`, and other parts.

Comment: Do you have a link to the source for the markup extensions and tools?

Comment: Unfortunately the code is not public, so you'd have to use the approach you mentioned earlier - reverse-engineering https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/extensions/Markup/Markup.js.